# How to capture a destination path before a workbook is saved there?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook "C:/abc.xlsm".

Then I try to save it as "C:/mno/xyz.xlsm".

I would like to trap the saving operation (I can use Workbook_BeforeSave to do that) and then I need to see what the desired destination path would be.

For example I would like to be able to do sth like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim destinationPath As String
    destinationPath = CaptureDestionationPath
    If InStr(1, destinationPath, "C:") Then
        Dim msgboxAnswer As Integer
        msgboxAnswer = MsgBox("It seems you are trying to save the file on your local drive. Is that intended", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "")
        If msgboxAnswer = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

As for what I tried: going through Workbook object properties and doing a websearch.

Comment: What's the value of that `SaveAsUI` parameter when you *Save*? What's its value when you *SaveAs*?

Comment: @Mat'sMug, True for SaveAs and False for Save.

Comment: If you step through this in the debugger you'll notice that the Save As dialog doesn't appear until ***after*** the event exits.  If you need to capture the file path, you need to show your own save as dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: the `Before-Save` is canceled and your save-as dialog is displayed. This dialog returns the save-as path which you can validate then. Finally events are disabled so the `Me.SaveAs fileSaveName` method don't raises the `Before-Save` event again.

*Note : you should add if-check of the variable `SaveAsUI` to distinguish between Save-As and simple Save.*

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True

    Dim fileSaveName
    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename
    If fileSaveName = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If InStr(1, fileSaveName, "C:") Then
        Dim msgboxAnswer As Integer
        msgboxAnswer = MsgBox("It seems you are trying to save the file on your local drive. Is that intended", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "")
        If msgboxAnswer = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Me.SaveAs fileSaveName
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that the nested Cancel won't do anything, since the first thing you do is set the cancel to True. And the final save will execute regardless of the answer. Isn't it? Anyway, yes, I get the logic (actually I coded it after the instructions from the comments to the question, but you gave the answer that I am physically able to accept).

Comment: Yes thats right, I have edited the answer, thanks :).